# How to select the sheets to print?

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have a macro that creates reports based on employee name. Each created report sheet is named with each employee's name.

When the employee generating the report presses the print button, it only prints the active sheet. This has to be done for each employee.

Is there a way in VBA to allow the user to select one or more employee names (based on the sheet name) and print all reports in one print job?

Comment: https://www.xelplus.com/list-box-to-print-multiple-sheets-excel-vba/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the code to print the sheets already, perhaps something like the below to print selected sheets. (Select the sheets while keeping the Ctrl key pressed).

```
Sub PrintMySheets()
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    
    For Each wsh In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

        Call YourMacro(wsh.Name)

    Next wsh

End Sub
```

Any code that points to the active sheet in your macro will need to be modified to work with the wsh parameter.